# C# 2 DataGridViews, one sets filter on another (this works fine) but Delete in "master" causing havoc

Tags: c#, datagridview

The following code works fine to set a filter on a table, based upon a value in another one (so as scroll in one DataGridView, another one displays correct details):

```
private void dgvCompany_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (dgvCompany.CurrentCell != null) 
     {
          DataView dv = new DataView();
          dv.Table = htctDataSet.co_lang;
          int irow = dgvCompany.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
          DataRow daRow = htctDataSet.company.Rows[irow];  // use this to get value used in filter below:
          string s = daRow.Field<int>("company_id").ToString(); // this throw exception after doing a delete
          dv.RowFilter = "company_id = " + s; //edited to show above line is problem
          dgvLang.DataSource = dv; 
     }
}
```

But when I delete a row in company (table in above that is used to set filter in other table), the dv.RowFilter line generates:
An unhandled exception of type

> 'System.Data.DeletedRowInaccessibleException'

The delete code is:

```
int irowCo = dgvCompany.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
DataTable dtCo = this.htctDataSet.company;
dtCo.Rows[irowCo].Delete();
//dtCo.AcceptChanges();
```

If I uncomment above line, then no exceptions are thrown, BUT,then I can NOT save to database

Save code (not showing transaction):

```
this.companyBindingSource.EndEdit();
this.companyTableAdapter.Update(this.htctDataSet.company);
```

My question is
How do I trap the above exception or how do I work around AcceptChanges() so that I can then save to database?

Comment: Could you not set the filter or second DataGridView's DataSource to none/null before you delete? Then rebind it after the delete?

Comment: I edited the source to show that the problem is with the first/master table.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a copy of the `DataTable`, to avoid coupling between the two methods.

```
          dv.Table = htctDataSet.co_lang.Copy();
```

---

```
private void dgvCompany_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (dgvCompany.CurrentCell != null) 
     {
          DataView dv = new DataView();
          dv.Table = htctDataSet.co_lang.Copy();
          int irow = dgvCompany.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
          DataRow daRow = htctDataSet.company.Rows[irow];  // use this to get value used in filter below:
          dv.RowFilter = "company_id = " + daRow.Field<int>("company_id").ToString(); // this throw exception after doing a delete
          dgvLang.DataSource = dv; 
     }
}
```

Comment: I edited the source to show that the problem is with the first/master table.  Sorry for the confusion.  I'll try the Copy on first/master table and see what happens.  Thanks for input.

Comment: Your suggestion set me on the right track, Thank you!  Here is what I did for anyone else having this problem - I created a Copy of the Table:   DataTable dtCo = new DataTable(); // master table

                dtCo = htctDataSet.company.Copy(); //key was Copy! Thank you!

                DataRow daRow = dtCo.Rows[irow]; 

                string s = daRow.Field<int>("company_id").ToString(); // this now works!